# Using a Linker Script on Mac OS X

Tags: gcc, macos, linker, linker-scripts

Is there any way to use a linker script with `ld` on Mac OS X?

The GNU `ld` program on Linux accepts a `-T <scriptname>` option, but on Mac OS -T is an unknown command option. Using an alternative installation of GCC is okay with me, if that solves the problem.

Comment: how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: If memory serves, I replaced the makefile entirely and thus _avoided_ the problem, not solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fink Project has [a document on porting Unix software to Darwin / Mac OS X](http://www.finkproject.org/doc/porting/porting.en.html), it claims that the Darwin linker isn't even based on the GNU linker.

I think you will have to read the `ld` man page to figure out how to do what you want with the native linker or install your own version of the GCC.

Comment: Run `ld -v` and you will see that the OS X linker is from the LLVM project.

Comment: But how does one install `gnu ld` on osx?

Comment: @gideon If you really need help with that, you should post a new question. Not many people are going to see your comment.